# MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to concatenate the result of a select but I can't because I get:

> ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

This is my code:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMNAS SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM (
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rita_development' AND TABLE_NAME = 'deals'
);
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMNAS SEPARATOR ', ') AS FINAL
FROM (
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMNAS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rita_development' AND TABLE_NAME = 'deals'
);
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Add an x after your last parentheses  `..AND TABLE_NAME = 'deals') x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, add a table alias:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM (
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rita_development' AND TABLE_NAME = 'deals'
) tablealias;
```

(every derived table must have its own alias!) but since you don't need a subquery/derived table, you can just use this:

```
SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME separator ', ')
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rita_development' AND TABLE_NAME = 'deals'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong name i select and missing the as table in subselect

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMNAS SEPARATOR ', ') 
 FROM (SELECT COLUMN_NAME as COLUMNAS
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rita_development' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'deals') as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( COLUMNAS SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS FINAL
FROM (
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMNAS
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rita_development' AND TABLE_NAME = 'deals') x
```